# Android SDK for eclipse using Google Play Services Lib: Error "Target runtime jre1.8.0_25 is not defined."

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

For university, I am working on an android-project, which uses the "Google Play Services Lib".
However, my eclipse throws an error, stating, that the "Target runtime jre1.8.0_25 is not defined.".
This being a git project, I have not installed/configured the library myself, though for others it seems to work flawlessly.
Being not very well versed with eclipse, I have tried to check every reference to the aforementioned jre in the projects settings, though I was out of luck, a quick fix isn't available either.

Comment: Ha you tried installing java 8 on your machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs to you because developing android does not support JDK 1.8
To solve this problem you need to install JDK 1.7(you might need to uninstall JDK 1.8, but it is for sure that you need JDK 1.7). This will solve your problem.

The last check you need to do is Project > Properties > Java Compiler(here you have to select 1.7 or 1.6)

Comment: I have only JDK 8 installed on my machine and i can build, i think checking the Java Compiler Version is the solution