# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML in one specific device

Tags: java, android, inflate-exception

I have a very frustrated error, that I cannot explain. I create an Android application. 
This is the XML of the problem.

widget_mapa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/quilmes_gray_fafafa"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- compact view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/compactViewContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/base_item_size"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/base_item_size"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_titulo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Ubicación"
            android:textColor="@color/quilmes_blue"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_detalle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="geolocalizada"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="11.5sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/base_item_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/base_item_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_dark_abajo" />
</LinearLayout>


<!-- full view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullViewContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <include layout="@layout/double_line_separator" />

    <!-- frecuency -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullFrequencyContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is main code of my activity :

LinearMapa.java

```
public class LinearMapa extends LinearLayout {
private Activity activity;
private Context ctx;
private Cliente pdv;

public LinearMapa(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    try {
        this.ctx = context;
        this.loadViewComponents();
        this.loadListeners();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public LinearMapa(Context context, Activity activity,Cliente pdv) {
    super(context);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.loadViewComponents();
    this.loadListeners();
    this.pdv = pdv;

}




/**
 * LAYOUT_ID
 */
public static final int LAYOUT_ID = R.layout.widget_mapa;

/**
 * compactViewContainer
 */
private LinearLayout compactViewContainer;
private TextView tvTitulo;
private TextView tv_detalle;
private LinearLayout fullViewContainer;

/**
 * compactComerceName
 */
private TextView compactComerceName;

/**
 * compactAddress
 */
private TextView compactAddress;


/**
 * compactCodPdv
 */
private TextView compactCodPdv;


private void loadViewComponents() {
    try {
    // generate view
    (LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext())).inflate(LAYOUT_ID, this);

    // load UI
    this.compactViewContainer = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.compactViewContainer);
    this.fullViewContainer = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.fullViewContainer);
    this.tvTitulo = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_titulo);
    this.tv_detalle = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_detalle);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The main problem here is : above code run smoothly on almost devices (ANDROID KITKAT or LOLLIPOP ). But when I run it on  lower versions ICS come this error.

```
.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class chess.samandroid.view.general.widget.LinearMapa
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class chess.samandroid.view.general.widget.LinearMapa
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at chess.samandroid.view.cliente.activities.Cliente.onCreate(Cliente.java:149)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at chess.samandroid.view.cliente.activities.Cliente.onCreate(Cliente.java:149)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4734)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at chess.samandroid.view.general.widget.LinearMapa.loadViewComponents(LinearMapa.java:92)
            at chess.samandroid.view.general.widget.LinearMapa.<init>(LinearMapa.java:39)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at chess.samandroid.view.cliente.activities.Cliente.onCreate(Cliente.java:149)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**GRADLE**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        //maven { url 'http://dt-imac-ba-032:8082/nexus/content/repositories/legacy/' }
        // flatDir { dirs 'libs' }

        maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':qRCodeReaderViewlib')
    compile('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    //compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        // debug {
        //    storeFile file("../keystore/sam.keystore")
        //}
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to fix error, thanks :)

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable ... have you included googlePlay services dependency in your gradle file. Please provide build.gradle file too

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.LinearMapa) change to  setContentView(R.layout.widget_mapa);

Comment: added gradle @Ramesh

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
this along with metadata in androidmanifest is what we need to do for maps setup. !!
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

Comment: can you check if you have both requirements satisfied

Comment: after change play-service 7.5.0 have  this error,     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$SlidingPanelLayoutImplJBMR1
            at android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout.<clinit>(SlidingPaneLayout.java:200)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
       ....   @Ramesh

Comment: Can you please try to be on 4.0 google play services only and try the answer i gave below. Using supportMapFragment.

Comment: is your problem solved

Comment: If I change MapFragment to SupprtFragment  then  I have to modify a lot of coding. Is   there another option to fix this error? 
The manifest is fine and the play-service now is in 4.0 and the project is working on Kitkat but not in ICS
@Ramesh

Comment: I dont think too much code. only imports needs to be changed because supportFragment almost has all the methods that mapFragment was using. just that this has support for previous verions as well.. 
and As far as I know No other options to make it work on lower devices without supportMapFragment

Comment: same error with FragmentActivity and  SupportMapFragment

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)  @Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

I think your error will go away if you use com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment instead MapFragment.

MapFragment expects minimum version of android to be 11. Use supportMapFragment whenever you want to go below sdk version 11.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The solution was change jdk1.8.0_40 too jdk1.7.0_75
go to project structure and change jdk 1.8 to jdk1.7
I Don't know why this could bring that error. If some one know please explain to me..

Comment: good to know you fixed issue yourself :) 
from following posts it looks developing android does not support jdk1.8 it seems. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622370/android-sdk-for-eclipse-using-google-play-services-lib-error-target-runtime-jr

Comment: yes, but that is for eclipse. In my case my work is in Android Studio